# macOS XPC Service not starting

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, xpc

I have a desktop Swift app with a single XPC service that has stopped working. I've managed to get it working once since, but it is back to being broken. I've tried reducing the code to the simplest case but it feels like there is a factor I don't understand.

Init Code:

```
connection = NSXPCConnection(serviceName: XPCBundleID)
connection.remoteObjectInterface = NSXPCInterface(withProtocol:UploadServiceProtocol.self)
connection.resume()
```

Test Function:

```
func initService(){
    let uploaderRemoteObject = connection.remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler() {
    (error) in NSLog("UploadServiceClient - remote proxy error: %@", error)
    } as! UploadServiceProtocol
    uploaderRemoteObject.initService?(nil) { (data) in
        NSLog("UploadServiceClient - initService - Got \(data?.length) bytes.")
    }

}
```

If I print the `uploaderRemoteObject` I get `<_NSXPCDistantObjectWithError: 0x618000083980>` Which may be normal, but the actual XPC process never gets spun up (and the remote method of course is not called).

The Service protocol is:

```
@objc(UploadServiceProtocol) protocol UploadServiceProtocol {
optional func initService(action:String?, withReply: (NSData?)->Void )
}
```

And the contents of the XPC main.swift is:

```
class ServiceDelegate: NSObject, NSXPCListenerDelegate {
    func listener(listener: NSXPCListener, shouldAcceptNewConnection newConnection: NSXPCConnection) -> Bool {
        newConnection.exportedInterface = NSXPCInterface(withProtocol: UploadServiceProtocol.self)
        newConnection.exportedObject = ImageUploader()
        newConnection.resume()
        return true
    }
}
let delegate = ServiceDelegate()
let listener = NSXPCListener.serviceListener()
listener.delegate = delegate;
listener.resume()
```

Note that I am sure that the `XPCBundleID` is correct, and I am signing everything for the Mac App Store. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, i'm dealing with similar situation where both my client and server are swift (server runs as agent by launchd and client is just a prompt command-line executable) and the connection cannot be established - i saw this since i implemented `invalidationHandler` in `NSXPCConnection` at client side.. perhaps you can suggest me how to debug this issue ? I haven't signed neither side, do you think it can be a problem ? is there any what to get the error ID and understand the root-cause of the problem ? thanks

Answer (score 5):

Solved it: Apparently you can't have optional functions in the XPC remote Protocol. Removing the `optional` from `UploadServiceProtocol` fixed it.